# How to download multiple files from firebase using downloadURL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

I have this code:

```
 fetch("/downloadFiles?" + new URLSearchParams({ items: currCart })) // fetching from my server all the download urls 
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => { // data is returned as an object - {items: [array of urls]}
data.items.forEach((element, index) => {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = currCart[index];
  link.href = element;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  });
})}
```

but instead of downloading the files it opens them in my browser.
The currCart[index] is just the wanted name of the downloaded file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download a file, we need to create a **Cloud Storage reference** to the file we want to download, to do that, you can create a reference by appending child paths to the root of your Cloud Storage `bucket` to then, download data via URL calling the `getDownloadURL()` method on a Cloud Storage reference.

If you want to download data directly from the **SDK**
(from version 9.5 and higher) it already provides these functions for direct download using **getBlob()**, **getStream()** available only in Node.js, **getBlob()** only for browser-like environments.

But if you need to download data directly in the browser, you must configure your Cloud Storage bucket for cross-origin access **(CORS)**. Add this `JSON` to a file named `cors.json`.

```json
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

To deploy these restrictions and set your bucket, run the following command:

```bash
$ gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>
```

**JS file**

```js
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

// Create a reference to the file we want to download
const storage = getStorage();
const starsRef = ref(storage, 'images/stars.jpg');

// Get the download URL
getDownloadURL(starsRef)
  .then((url) => {
    // <---------------- Insert url file here!
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // A full list of error codes is available at
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/object-not-found':
        // File doesn't exist
        break;
      case 'storage/unauthorized':
        // User doesn't have permission to access the object
        break;
      case 'storage/canceled':
        // User canceled the upload
        break;

      // ...

      case 'storage/unknown':
        // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
        break;
    }
  });
```

Doesn't matter what format you want to use, just **insert the URL** or the reference link (PDF,  GIF, image, video, etc) of the file we want to show inside the function `getDownloadURL()` and same process with the `<iframe>`.

> PDF file for example in **HTML document** is `<a href="">` tag with **href** attribute for the url or path if you are self hosting the file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>PDF Example</h1>
    <p>Download PDF file <a href="/assets/pdf/5cb701example.pdf">here</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! But what if I don’t want specifically an image, in this case I get urls for pdf files

Comment: You 're welcome, doesn't matter about the extension file, add the HTML segment to your JS or JSX component, I edited the answer, let me know! @Navav Holtzman